# What is the reason encountering "already has a body" error and how to fix it? in my C++ project

Tags: c++, function

I'm working on a project that consists of sharing objects between multiple classes.

```
User::User(string username) {  // constructor of User class
    this->name = &username; 
    num_comments = new unsigned int(0);
}
```

this is my implementation of constructor in cpp file and the definition of class in header file is

```
class User {  

private:
    string *name; 
    vector<Post> posts; 
    unsigned int *num_comments; 

public:
    
    User(string username)   {}
    ~User() {}
     Post& createPost(string content); 
     
    vector<Post*> getPosts(); 
    int getnumcomments();
    string getName(); 
};
```

When I try to run my code, I entounter with error C2084: function 'User::User(std::string)' already has a body

I encounter the same error with my other constructors and destructors. So, my mistake is general.
What is the reason?

Comment: `User(string username)   {}` Remove the brackets.

Comment: Thanks for warnings. This is the first time I'm using stackoverflow to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved my problem.  I need to practice a lot  in order to avoid syntax related mistakes

Comment: `this->name = &username;` This takes the address of the argument. The argument goes away when the constructor returns, and the address stored in `name` is meaningless. Simple solution: don't use a pointer. `std::string name;` will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells it explicitly: you define `User::User` twice. Once outside and once inside the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In your header file, you are defining the constructor with an empty body:

```
User(string username)   {}
```

And then in your cpp file, you are defining the same constructor with a non-empty body:

```
User::User(string username) {  // constructor of User class
    this->name = &username; 
    num_comments = new unsigned int(0);
}
```

Hence the error.  To solve this, in the header file, you need to replace the braces with a semicolon instead:

```
User(string username);
```